# HTML table <td> width discrepancy between two table

Tags: html, html-table

I have a requirement in which I have to show quarter months with quarter name on the starting month. For eg.

```
                  Q120                   Q220
```

COL1 COL2 COL3 APR-19 MAY-19 JUN-19 JUL-19 AUG-19 SEP19

For that I created two tables, one table to print quarters and other to print other columns and their data.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="70px"></td>
    <td width="70px"></td>
    <td width="70px"></td>
    <td width="210px">Q120</td>
    <td width="210px">Q220</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="70px">COL1</td>
    <td width="70px">COL2</td>
    <td width="70px">COL3</td>
    <td width="70px">APR-19</td>
    <td width="70px">MAY-19</td>
    <td width="70px">JUN-19</td>
    <td width="70px">JUL-19</td>
    <td width="70px">AUG-19</td>
    <td width="70px">SEP-19</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Whats wrong with my code ? I am NOT getting proper alignment as explained in my example . My quarter row is shifting towards left side ideally Q120 should come above APR-19.

Comment: It's not clear from what you wrote how the expected result should look like. It might help to post an image depicting the desired layout.

Comment: did you use the inspector? you could force the width using inline style for each `<td>`. don't forget table headers if you need to label the rows too. everything seems to be lining up right. can you describe the desired output better

Comment: As Constantin mentions... What is your desired result? A screenshot or working HTML example would be helpful, so we know what we need to try in order to help you.